# Syntax error unrecognized expression wrap html tag to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What's wrong here?

```
var str = 'Text coming from the caption of this image. The caption describes the photo and can be short, or very long. This can keep going on multiple lines but should be truncated if too long otherwise the summary window will grow very big';
$(str).wrap('<div></div>');
```

This seem legit to me. Anything wrong for the string?

https://jsbin.com/lecuregede/1/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `$(str)`, `str` must be either a selector or an HTML string. In your case, since it doesn't begin with an HTML tag, it's assumed to be a selector. But it's just some random text, and when it tries to parse it as a selector it gets an error. The problem is the word `image.` in the string, that's not a valid selector because it has `.` at the end of the word, and `.` has to be followed by a class name.

To put text in a `div`, use it as the `text` of a new `<div>` element:

```
$('<div>', { text: str })
```

Comment: how to you explain when you do `var str = 'hello';` the error is gone?

Comment: That's a valid selector, it will match an element like `<hello>`.

Comment: Try to see this example I've created to explain my problem https://jsbin.com/pawiremamu/1/edit

Comment: It's like doing `$('hello')` -- it's a selector looking for that tag name. It doesn't return anything because there are no `<hello>` elements in the DOM. But it's not a syntax error any more.

Comment: Try doing `$('image.')` and you'll get the error. A selector can't have `.` at the end of a word, it has to be at the beginning, because it means to select elements with that class.

Comment: I got it. Thanks @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

You're calling jQuery on `str`, which is just a plain string. Try surrounding it with an HTML element like a `div` or `span`.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with wrapping string, try to change var str value to 'hello'

Comment: Ah, you're right. It looks like it's choking on the `.`. Probably trying to interpret that as a class selector.

Comment: @NatelyJamerson I explained that in my comments above, why don't you understand?

Comment: @Barmar No, choking means?

Comment: @NatelyJamerson Compare the result of `$('div')` with `$('div.')`. The first works, the second gets an error because of `.` at the end of the word.

Comment: Look in your original `str`, it contains `image.`. That's causing the error, because you can't have `.` at the end of a word in a selector.

Comment: @NatelyJamerson Something like `$('this is a div')` means to look for `<this>` element that contains `<is>`, which contains `<a>`, which contains `<div>`. Now do you get it?